# Change type of an object's property based on another property's value in class variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

**TL;DR TypeScript type inference fails in class when using union types**

I've ran into an issue with typescript when dealing with classes and union types.

This is a basic version of the types that i've got:

```js
type CommonData = {
    name: string
}

type Dog = {
    age: number
} & CommonData

type Bat = {
    wingspan: number
} & CommonData

type Animal = {
    type: "dog"
    data: Dog
} | {
    type: "bat"
    data: Bat
}
```

The `Animal` type changes its data type based on the value of the type field.

So, when creating objects using the `Animal` type, typescript is able to determine what type of data is used for each animal based on the type field. Example below:

```js
const bat: Animal = {
    type: "bat",
    data: {
        name: "tim",
        wingspan: 9000
    }
}

// has type inference, 
bat.data.name
```

However, when implementing the same type in a class, typescript doesn't recognize what type of data is returned. Here's an example of what my current code is like:

```js
class AnimalClass {
    animal: Animal

    constructor (animal: Animal) {
        this.animal = animal
    }
}

const dog = new AnimalClass({
    type: "dog",
    data: {
        name: "bob",
        age: 10
    }
})

// no type inference on data, typescript doesn't know that it's a Dog
dog.animal.data
```

dog.animal.data has a type of `Dog | Bat`. Is it possible to alter the code to infer that the type of dog.animal.data is `Dog`

Thanks in advance :)

Here's the full code: [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwXAdgEQIbA1AvFAbwCgpSoUMEIAuKAZ2ACcBLFAcyIF8ijRIo0cNnkIkyGNjXIBXBACMIjLlABksRMnRYMPPtABCWEcTJQA7qzZ0wGFLRSyFSzqvVJUmbLvDQAgimYEDAAbYzFSPVoAIgATISjwqBjtWkEOFwAfUVNIqCi5LATTZOxaQ2AuHgBjVAYoAuBaf0CQsJyfaIaogBpEkoxaE1MyCipo4ECexNMLdmtbWgBOAAZVxO5uIgB6LagACww6KD0oVgAzRQgUKogiBoA6fvvR26Iq4MOj5qDgmA+6I5DUi2FrBJoBH48Uw1FAMRjSKrAOCMKAAChBP3BoIAlNlhhE9sw6PcMa18KTgutKm9asAkkIRCgIGYoN8Qn9PqigccOnk4mwpsUUnj8S9OnA5IL8VAJFIAIzLKmcbE8HbkOA8-jnS7XaCoJLabqaiB0KosMB0uImlAAcjpAGsUHAWcADnTmMAbUccGkiPySRCQo9tGIgA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a generic annotaion on the Animal class as the following, to make the inference complete:

```
class AnimalClass<T extends Animal> {
    animal: T;

    constructor (animal: T) {
        this.animal = animal
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://ode/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwXAdgEQIbA1AvFAbwCgpSoUMEIAuKAZ2ACcBLFAcyIF8ijRIo0cNnkIkyGNjXIBXBACMIjLlABksRMnRYMPPtABCWEcTJQA7qzZ0wGFLRSyFSzqvVJUmbLvDQAgimYEDAAbYzFSPVoAIgATISjwqBjtWkEOFwAfUVNIqCi5LATTZOxaQ2AuHgBjVAYoAuBaf0CQsJyfaIaogBpEkoxaE1MyCipo4ECexNMLdmtbWgBOAAZVxO5uIgB6LagACww6KD0oVgAzRQgUKogiBoA6fvvR26Iq4MOj5qDgmA+6OgAHgAKlAIAAPYBXGJfAI-AB82XEcJCtGBAG4eKYaigGIxpFVgHBGFAABS2FrBNEASiRw2Oe2YdHuFJ+IlZIXWlTetWASSEIhQEDMUG+IT+n1JQwiHTycTYU2KKTpwxenTgckV9KgEikAEZllzONSeDtyHBjj5TigLowrjcoKgktpupbIHQqiwwHy4hA6CgAOR8gDWKDgIuABz5zGAAaOODSRHlLJRwUe2hZkkxpCAA)